# Analyzer that checks project references

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'd like to create a solution that controls the project references in C# projects. Ideally, this solution is IDE-agnostic so that it can be used with Visual Studio, Jetbrains Rider, or even VS Code. The reason for this is that I've seen solutions that are completely messed up due to people creating almost arbitrary project references. It's super hard to get them straight after a project has grown to a certain size.

I know that Visual Studio Enterprise offers this out-of-the-box. Unfortunately, in my current company we do not have VS Enterprise. Thus, I want to create that on my own.

So what would be the best way to do it? After doing some research I think leveraging the **.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")** with its Workspace API might be a good idea? Seems like I could deploy it as a NuGet package which can then be used in any IDE or build-automation. But maybe there's an easier or better way, I'd like to hear your opinion on that before I start digging into it.

Also: if the "Roslyn"-way is the right one is there some good resources on how to create an analyzer that works with the Workspace APIs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roslyn analyzes C#, I think you want a tool that analyzes sln and csproj files.

Comment: Basically, you're right. But Roslyn offers the Workspace API, this should suit my needs, shouldn't it? If not what would be the alternative to check for project references?

Comment: [`Solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Solution.cs,21e7cdafcc9eda8f) should get you started.

Comment: @Sievajet thanks, but how do I get a reference to the current solution if I'm working in a DiagnosticAnalyzer? DiagnosticAnalyzers do not seem to be build for doing that kind of analyzing. They really only seem to be there for analzying C# syntax and semantics, but not really project-related stuff.

Comment: Thats true. You’ll have to build it yourself. Currently there isn’t any api that does this for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your analyser, register a compilation start action:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterCompilationStartAction(Initialize);
}

private void Initialize(CompilationStartAnalysisContext context)
{
    var compilation = context.Compilation;
}
```

From that compilation object, you have various options:

```
var referencedAssemblyNames = compilation.ReferencedAssemblyNames;
```

or

```
var references = compilation.References;
```

Then do your analysis. To report diagnostics, register an action on the `CompilationStartAnalysisContext` using `context.RegisterCompilationEndAction`.

If you don't need to look at actual project content for your analysis, you can simply use `RegisterCompilationAction` as follows:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public sealed class TooManyReferencesAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static DiagnosticDescriptor TooManyReferences { get; } =
        new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            "DEMO",
            "Don't use too many references",
            "The project '{0}' has {1} references",
            category: "Maintainability",
            defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
            isEnabledByDefault: true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics =>
        ImmutableArray.Create(TooManyReferences);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterCompilationAction(AnalyzeCompilation);
    }

    private void AnalyzeCompilation(CompilationAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var compilation = context.Compilation;
        int referenceCount = compilation.References.Count();

        if (referenceCount > 5)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(
                Diagnostic.Create(
                    TooManyReferences,
                    null,
                    compilation.AssemblyName,
                    referenceCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u give me an example of that? I tried to create an analyzer that registers with RegisterCompilationStartAction(startCtx) and then registers an RegisterCompilationEndAction on the startCtx. The code in the StartAction is called constantly while the code in the EndAction where I could report diagnostics is never called. It also says something like 'startCtx does not register any analyzer actions, except for CompilationEndAction. Consider replacing this start/end action pair with ...' I get the feeling that I do not understand the compiler actions somehow.

Comment: Maybe u can provide an example where you report an error as soon as the total number of references is higher than a specific number? Just to show how to use it properly.

Comment: @baumgarb Example given.