# How to validate Projects property default namespace with Roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

I want to validate the the property which is visible in the project only and that's a default namespace value on compile action. I was able to find ability to [validate project references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654423/analyzer-that-checks-project-references) but this does not provide option to read the default project's namespace.

Is it possible to do with Roslyn Analyzer?

**Edit:** I found that during Compilation start there is available some property but this does not give wanted information:

```
context.Compilation.GlobalNamespace.IsNamespace > returns true
context.Compilation.GlobalNamespace.IsGlobalNamespace > returns true
context.Compilation.GlobalNamespace.Name > returns ""
context.Compilation.GlobalNamespace.ToDisplayString() > returns "<global namespace>"
```

I know that I can go to each class and check the namespace but this is not the case since I want to know the default project's namespace. An example:
project name="Project.UnitTests", assembly="Project.UnitTests" and default namespace is "Project.UnitTest". The default namespace is not matching project since project name is plural and namespace is single meaning.

Comment: You can do it with MSBuild.

Comment: How? Any examples?

Comment: What validation do you want to perform?

Comment: I want to check for default global namespace only and show compiler error if violated rule. The same way as any other diagnostic error shown in Visual studio. Same way as I did for the references check for the project.

Comment: The [MSBuild Error Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/error-task?view=vs-2019) causes a build error.

Comment: Not really clear if this is possible to achieve as per example. How about created new project which does not fall into rules? How about project where validation should not be applied?

Comment: Examples: RealCode.Project with RealCode namespace - no validation required; Code.UnitTest with namespace Code.UnitTest - should fail due .UnitTest added to namespace. Validation should consider Including capitalization check too and etc. There are many scenarios. Having this as part of project defeats the purpose of validation since usually problem is in the new projects but not limited.
Maybe possible to have targets files with such a sophisticated check would make sense if Analyzer cannot do this.

Comment: You can do a lot with [MSBuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019). `RootNamespace` is used by tooling to infer the namespace of generated assets. It's not part of the compilation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it is for C# Source Generator, is not for Analyzer, but anyway I was succeeded in getting the root namespace of the target project in my source generator.

The document of detail is here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#consume-msbuild-properties-and-metadata

At first, you have to declare `<CompilerVisibleProperty>` item in the item group of the target project file (it is not a source generator project file) to allow your source generator to retrieve the specified MSBUild property value.
In this case, you should specify the `RootNamespace` property.

```xml
...
<!-- This is the target application's .csproj file -->
<ItemGroup>
  <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="RootNamespace" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

After that, you can get the root namespace by the code as below, instead of referencing `context.Compilation.GlobalNamespace`.

```
...
// This is C# Source Generator's .cs file.
[Generator]
public class MySourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        context.AnalyzerConfigOptions.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.RootNamespace", out var rootNamespace);
        ...
```

I'm not sure that this code can apply also C# Analyzor, but I hope this information helpful for you.